# TFS: Configure test agents for mulitiple physical web environments

Tags: testing, tfs, agent, microsoft-test-manager

Background:

- We are running all physical
  hardware.
- All developers are using
  VS 2010 Ultimate and we will be using
  iTrace files.
- We would like to run
  our coded UI tests from test manager.
- We have multiple test environments:
  AT, SIT, FVT, UAT living each on
  physical servers.

I’d like to be able to go into test manager select tests and say go run in AT or go run in FVT.

Here’s my question:
Do I set up interactive test agents on all of my test environments and instruct the coded UI tests to hit http://localhost/application?

Do I set up an interactive test agent on a another machine to execute the tests?  If so how do I configure the coded UI tests to point to each of the test servers?  Do I need test agents running as a process of the web servers?

Answer (score 0):

We are using the following *unsupported* Microsoft features: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lab_management/archive/2011/02/15/running-build-deploy-test-workflow-on-physical-environments.aspx

Actually, the blog describes exacly what you need and we got it up and running within a day like described, in a VMWare lab, without having the Lab Management pre-requisites deployed.